# Spring MVC + DATA JPA при обновлении родительского объекта удаляются дочерние из всех таблиц

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-jpa

Если запуск из консоли
**app.java**

```
public class app {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.load("classpath:app-context-annotation.xml");
        ctx.refresh();

        ClientService clientService = ctx.getBean("jpaClientService", ClientService.class);
        UserService userService = ctx.getBean("jpaUserService", UserService.class);
        CustomerService customerService = ctx.getBean("jpaCustomerService", CustomerService.class);
        TroubleService troubleService = ctx.getBean("jpaTroubleService", TroubleService.class);
        Client newClient = clientService.findOne(8l);
        String newClientName = "IP 8";
        newClient.setClient(newClientName);
        clientService.saveClient(newClient);
        clientList("Find all:", clientService.findAll());
        System.out.println(client.getUserList());*/
    }
    private static void clientList (String message, List<Client> clientList) {
        System.out.println(message);
        for (Client client : clientList) {
            System.out.println(client);
        }
    }
    private static void userList (String message, List<User> userList) {
        System.out.println(message);
        for (User user : userList) {
            System.out.println(user);
        }
    }
    private static void troubleList (String message, List<Trouble> troubleList) {
        System.out.println(message);
        for (Trouble trouble : troubleList) {
            System.out.println(trouble);
        }
    }
}
```

то в этом плане проблем нет, идет update только нужной таблицы.

**Client.java**

```
 @Entity
 @Table (name = "Client")
 public class Client implements Serializable{
     private Long id;
     private String inn;
     private int version;
     private String client;
     private ClientSpecific clientSpecific;
     private String address;
     private String phone;
     private List<User> UserList = new ArrayList<User>();
     private List<Trouble> TroubleList = new ArrayList<Trouble>();
     public Client (){}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id" )
    public Long getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id){
        this.id=id;
    }
    @Column(name = "inn")
    public String getInn(){
        return this.inn;
    }
    public void setInn (String inn){
        this.inn = inn;
    }
    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    public int getVersion(){
        return this.version;
    }
    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
    @Column(name = "client")
    public String getClient(){
        return this.client;
    }
    public void setClient(String client){
        this.client = client;
    }
    @Column(name = "client_specific")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public ClientSpecific getClientSpecific(){
        return this.clientSpecific;
    }
    public void setClientSpecific(ClientSpecific clientSpecific){
        this.clientSpecific = clientSpecific;
    }
     @Column(name = ("address"))
     public String getAddress(){
         return this.address;
     }
     public void setAddress(String address){
         this.address = address;
     }
     @Column(name = "phone")
     public String getPhone(){
         return this.phone;
     }
     public void setPhone(String phone){
         this.phone = phone;
     }

     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
     @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
     public List<User> getUserList(){
         return this.UserList;
     }
     public void setUserList(List<User> userList){
         this.UserList = userList;
     }

     public void addUser(User user){
         user.setClient(this);
         getUserList().add(user);
     }
     public void removeUser(User user){
         getUserList().remove(user);
     }
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
     @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
     public List<Trouble> getTroubleList(){
         return this.TroubleList;
     }
     public void setTroubleList(List<Trouble> troubleList){
         this.TroubleList = troubleList;
     }
     public void addTrouble(Trouble trouble) {
         trouble.setClient(this);
         getTroubleList().add(trouble);
     }
     public String toString() {
         return "Client ID - " + id + ", Client - " + client + ", INN - " + inn;
     }
}
```

**Trouble.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "trouble")
public class Trouble implements Serializable{
    private Long id;
    private String barcode;
    private Date incomDate;
    private Date outDate;
    private String caseDesc;
    private String result;
    private int paymentStatus;
    private float summCase;
    private Client client;
    private Customer customer;
    private int version;

    public Trouble(){}
    public Trouble(Long id, String barcode, Date incomDate, Date out_date, String caseDesc, String result, int paymentStatus, float summCase, int version){
        this.id = id;
        this.barcode = barcode;
        this.incomDate = incomDate;
        this.outDate = out_date;
        this.caseDesc = caseDesc;
        this.result = result;
        this.paymentStatus = paymentStatus;
        this.summCase = summCase;
        this.version = version;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Column (name = "barcode")
    public String getBarcode(){
        return barcode;
    }
    public void setBarcode (String barcode){
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column (name = "incom_date")
    public Date getIncomDate(){
        return incomDate;
    }
    public void setIncomDate(Date incomDate){
        this.incomDate = incomDate;
    }
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column (name = "out_date")
    public Date getOutDate(){
        return outDate;
    }
    public void setOutDate(Date outDate){
        this.outDate = outDate;
    }
    @Column (name = "case_desc")
    public String getCaseDesc(){
        return caseDesc;
    }
    public void setCaseDesc(String caseDesc){
        this.caseDesc = caseDesc;
    }
    @Column (name = "result")
    public String getResult(){
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(String result){
        this.result = result;
    }
    @Column (name = "payment_status")
    public int getPaymentStatus(){
        return paymentStatus;
    }
    public void setPaymentStatus(int paymentStatus){
        this.paymentStatus = paymentStatus;
    }
    @Column (name = "summ_case")
    public float getSummCase(){
        return summCase;
    }
    public void setSummCase(float summCase){
        this.summCase = summCase;
    }
    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    public int getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }
    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_trouble_client"))
    public Client getClient(){
        return this.client;
    }
    public void setClient (Client client){
        this.client = client;
    }
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_trouble_customer"))
    public Customer getCustomer(){
        return this.customer;
    }
    public void setCustomer (Customer customer){
        this.customer = customer;
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable{
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String middleName;
    //private String role;
    private String login;
    private String passw;
    private int version;
    private Client client;
    private UserRole role;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Long id,String firstName, String lastName, String middleName, UserRole role, String login, String passw, Client client, int version) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.role = role;
        this.login = login;
        this.passw = passw;
        this.client = client;
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    public String getMiddleName() {
        return this.middleName;
    }
    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }
    @Column(name = "role")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public UserRole getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }
    public void setRole(UserRole role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    @Column(name = "login")
    public String getLogin() {
        return this.login;
    }
    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
    @Column(name = "passw")
    public String getPassw() {
        return this.passw;
    }
    public void setPassw(String passw) {
        this.passw = passw;
    }
    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    public int getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }
    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_client"))
    public Client getClient(){
        return this.client;
    }
    public void setClient(Client client){
    this.client = client;
    }
}
```

**ClientController**

```
@RequestMapping("/clients")
@Controller

public class ClientController {
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ClientController.class);
    private ClientService clientService;
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list (Model uiModel) {
        log.info("Listing clients");
        List<Client> clients = clientService.findAll();
        uiModel.addAttribute("clients", clients);
        log.info("No. of Clients: " + clients.size());

        for (Client client : clients) {
            System.out.println(client);
        }
        return "clients/list";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String show(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model uiModel){
        Client client = clientService.findOne(id);
        uiModel.addAttribute("client", client);
        uiModel.addAttribute("users", client.getUserList());
        return "clients/show";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String update(Client client, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Locale locale){
        log.info("Updating client:");
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            uiModel.addAttribute("message", new Message("error", messageSource.getMessage("client_save_fail", new Object[]{}, locale)));
            uiModel.addAttribute("client", client);
            return "clients/update";
        }
        uiModel.asMap().clear();
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", new Message("success", messageSource.getMessage("client_save_success", new Object[]{}, locale)));
        clientService.saveClient(client);
        return "redirect:/clients/"+ UrlUtil.encodeUrlPathSegment(client.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String updateForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model uiModel){
        uiModel.addAttribute("client", clientService.findOne(id));
        return "clients/update";
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String create(Client client, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Locale locale){
        log.info("Creating Client:");
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            uiModel.addAttribute("message", new Message("error", messageSource.getMessage("client_create_fail", new Object[]{}, locale)));
            uiModel.addAttribute("client", client);
        }
        uiModel.asMap().clear();
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", new Message("success", messageSource.getMessage("client_create_success", new Object[]{}, locale)));
        clientService.saveClient(client);
        log.info("Client ID: " + client.getId() + "was created success");
        return "redirect:/clients/" + UrlUtil.encodeUrlPathSegment(client.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String createForm(Model uiModel){
        Client client = new Client();
        uiModel.addAttribute(client);
        return "clients/create";
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setClientService(@Qualifier("jpaClientService") ClientService clientService){
        this.clientService = clientService;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource){
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }
}
```

**ClientServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service("jpaClientService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ClientServiceImpl implements ClientService {
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ClientService.class);
    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Client> findAll() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(clientRepository.findAll());
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Client findOne(Long id) {
        log.info("Finding Client ID: " + id);
        Client client = clientRepository.findOne(id);
        //Hibernate.initialize(client.getUserList().size());
        //Hibernate.initialize(client.getTroubleList().size());
        return client;
    }

    public Client saveClient(Client client) {
        Client savedClient = clientRepository.saveAndFlush(client);
        if (client.getId() == null) {
            log.info("Client INN: " + client.getInn() + " inserting.");
        } else {
            log.info("Client ID: " + client.getId() + " updating.");
        }
        return savedClient;
    }

    public void deleteClient(Long id) {
        clientRepository.delete(id);
        log.info("Client ID: " + id + " was deleted.");
    }
}
```

**edit.jspx**

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
          xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
          xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
          xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_info" var="labelClientInfo"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_client" var="labelClient"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_id" var="labelId"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_inn" var="labelInn"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_specific" var="labelClientSpecific"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_address" var="labelClientAddress"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_phone" var="labelClientPhone"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_update" var="labelClientUpdate"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_new" var="labelClientNew"/>
    <spring:eval expression="client.id == null ? labelClientNew:labelClientUpdate" var="formTitle"/>
    <html>
    <head><title>${formTitle}</title></head>
    <body>
    <h1>${formTitle}</h1>
    <div id="contactUpdate">
        <form:form modelAttribute="client" id="clientUpdateForm" method="post">
            <c:if test="${not empty message}">
                <div id="message" class="${message.type}">"${message.message}"</div>
            </c:if>
            <form:label path="client">
                ${labelClient}
            </form:label>
            <form:input path="client"/>
            <div>
                <form:errors path="client" cssClass="error"/>
            </div>
            <form:label path="inn">
                ${labelInn}
            </form:label>
            <form:input path="inn"/>
            <div>
                <form:errors path="inn" cssClass="error"/>
            </div>
            <form:label path="address">
                ${labelClientAddress}
            </form:label>
            <form:input path="address"/>
            <div>
                <form:errors path="address" cssClass="error"/>
            </div>
            <form:label path="phone">
                ${labelClientPhone}
            </form:label>
            <form:input path="phone"/>
            <div>
                <form:errors path="phone" cssClass="error"/>
            </div>
            <form:label path="clientSpecific">
                ${labelClientSpecific}
            </form:label>
            <form:select path="clientSpecific">
                <form:options items="${clientSpecific}"/>
            </form:select>
            <form:hidden path="version"/>
            <br/>
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
            <button type="reset">Reset</button>
        </form:form>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
</jsp:root>
```

**view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles
        Configuration 3.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition extends="default" name="clients/list">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/clients/list.jspx" />
    </definition>
    <definition extends="default" name="clients/show">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/clients/show.jspx"/>
    </definition>
    <definition extends="default" name="clients/update">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/clients/edit.jspx"/>
    </definition>
    <definition extends="default" name="clients/create">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/clients/edit.jspx"/>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

**Log**
Попутно вопрос - откуда Left Outer??

```
23:52:22,447  INFO http-nio-8080-exec-10 controllers.ClientController:53 - Updating client:
Hibernate: 
    /* load ru.chirkovds.springtest.entity.Client */ select
        client0_.id as id1_0_1_,
        client0_.address as address2_0_1_,
        client0_.client as client3_0_1_,
        client0_.client_specific as client_s4_0_1_,
        client0_.inn as inn5_0_1_,
        client0_.phone as phone6_0_1_,
        client0_.version as version7_0_1_,
        troublelis1_.client_id as client_10_2_3_,
        troublelis1_.id as id1_2_3_,
        troublelis1_.id as id1_2_0_,
        troublelis1_.barcode as barcode2_2_0_,
        troublelis1_.case_desc as case_des3_2_0_,
        troublelis1_.client_id as client_10_2_0_,
        troublelis1_.customer_id as custome11_2_0_,
        troublelis1_.incom_date as incom_da4_2_0_,
        troublelis1_.out_date as out_date5_2_0_,
        troublelis1_.payment_status as payment_6_2_0_,
        troublelis1_.result as result7_2_0_,
        troublelis1_.summ_case as summ_cas8_2_0_,
        troublelis1_.version as version9_2_0_ 
    from
        Client client0_ 
    left outer join
        trouble troublelis1_ 
            on client0_.id=troublelis1_.client_id 
    where
        client0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        userlist0_.client_id as client_i9_3_0_,
        userlist0_.id as id1_3_0_,
        userlist0_.id as id1_3_1_,
        userlist0_.client_id as client_i9_3_1_,
        userlist0_.first_name as first_na2_3_1_,
        userlist0_.last_name as last_nam3_3_1_,
        userlist0_.login as login4_3_1_,
        userlist0_.middle_name as middle_n5_3_1_,
        userlist0_.passw as passw6_3_1_,
        userlist0_.role as role7_3_1_,
        userlist0_.version as version8_3_1_ 
    from
        user userlist0_ 
    where
        userlist0_.client_id=?
Hibernate: 
    /* delete ru.chirkovds.springtest.entity.Trouble */ delete 
        from
            trouble 
        where
            id=? 
            and version=?
Hibernate: 
    /* delete ru.chirkovds.springtest.entity.User */ delete 
        from
            user 
        where
            id=? 
            and version=?
23:52:22,716  INFO http-nio-8080-exec-10 service.ClientService:43 - Client ID: 8 updating.
23:52:22,813  INFO http-nio-8080-exec-1 service.ClientService:31 - Finding Client ID: 8
Hibernate: 
    select
        client0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        client0_.address as address2_0_0_,
        client0_.client as client3_0_0_,
        client0_.client_specific as client_s4_0_0_,
        client0_.inn as inn5_0_0_,
        client0_.phone as phone6_0_0_,
        client0_.version as version7_0_0_ 
    from
        Client client0_ 
    where
        client0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        userlist0_.client_id as client_i9_3_0_,
        userlist0_.id as id1_3_0_,
        userlist0_.id as id1_3_1_,
        userlist0_.client_id as client_i9_3_1_,
        userlist0_.first_name as first_na2_3_1_,
        userlist0_.last_name as last_nam3_3_1_,
        userlist0_.login as login4_3_1_,
        userlist0_.middle_name as middle_n5_3_1_,
        userlist0_.passw as passw6_3_1_,
        userlist0_.role as role7_3_1_,
        userlist0_.version as version8_3_1_ 
    from
        user userlist0_ 
    where
        userlist0_.client_id=?
```

Не могу понять - где нарукожопил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из вашего вопроса ничего, по сути понять нельзя, одни исходники... ))

Связи с подчиненными сущностями у вас присутствуют только в сущности Client

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
public List<User> getUserList()

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
public List<Trouble> getTroubleList()
```

Судя по всему, здесь "обновления" приводят к удалению строк из др. таблиц?

Если да, то это происходит потому, что указан каскад **CascadeType.ALL** и **orphanRemoval = true**.

**CascadeType.ALL** [включает в себя](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqm/index.html), в том числе, каскадное удаление.

А **orphanRemoval = true** [приводит к удалению объектов](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/), открепленных от зависимого.

В вашем случае, по-моему, достаточно использовать 
`cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}`.

Comment: Попробую по-другому объяснить. При обновлении родительского объекта удаляются дочерние, что НЕ нужно делать.
В Entity User и Trouble есть ManyToOne.

Comment: Это первый проект. Вообще первый. Совсем. Поэтому, что-то могу "криво" объяснять.
Если запустить из консоли (app.java), то обновление проходит корректно - т.е. родитель обновляется, дочерние на месте.
Но вот при обновлении того же родителя уже со страницы edit.jspx (через ClientController), дочерние удаляются.
app-context и webapp-context - одинаковые.
Подозреваю, что либо надо что-то в servlet-context дописАть, либо что-то в контроллере.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "обновлением родителя"? Можете точно объяснить? Кого пытаетесь редактировать, как именно редактируете (список подчиненных объектов, что ли)?

Comment: Или удаляете целиком "Родителя" или еще как-то? 

Мои рекомендации выше не помогли?

Comment: Беру Client, меняю одно поле. Сохраняю в базу.

Comment: Этот код НЕ удаляет дочерние Entity

`Client newClient = clientService.findOne(8l);
        String newClientName = "IP 8";
        newClient.setClient(newClientName);
        clientService.saveClient(newClient);`

Comment: По вашей рекомендации поймал Exception
org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: ru.chirkovds.springtest.entity.Client.userList

Comment: Из консоли Ваш код так же работает, как и мой. Родитель обновился, дочерние на месте (в базе).

Comment: Судя по вашему коду Client.java, изменение строкового поля `client` и не должно приводить к удалению дочерних объектов. Дочерние объекты, могут удалятся: 1) если вы удалите родителя (это сработает каскад = ALL); 2) если вы удалите из списка дочек какой нибудь элемент (сработает `orphanRemoval = true`). По поводу исключения - вы убрали из кода `orphanRemoval = true`?

Comment: Удалил - заработало вроде )
Огроменное спасибо. Видимо, я неправильно понял суть orphanRemoval. Либо все же где-то что-то не так.
Но все же я до Вас не смог донести то, что хотел. Либо я не совсем понял Вас. Если есть желание и возможность - могу попытаться еще раз (только уже не здесь, а, например, в аське).
Еще раз спасибо.